# pymssql/pyodbc performance (cursor.execute) is very slow when querying large SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql-server, performance, pyodbc, pymssql

We have a large view on SQL Server (with ca. 500M records). Since it won't fit into memory, I was thinking of processing in chunks using fetchmany like below:

```
with pymssql.connect(host, user, pass, db) as conn:

    query = f"SELECT * FROM view_name;"

    with conn.cursor() as cursor, futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(3) as executor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        chunk_size = 5000
        data = cursor.fetchmany(chunk_size)

        while data:
            future_rs = executor.submit(process_chunk, data)
            data = cursor.fetchmany(chunk_size)
```

However, looks like `cursor.execute` actually tries to fetch all rows before I can call fetchmany as it is extremely slow.

My understanding from docs is that `cursor.execute` should only prepare query and not materialize full results?

How would you process such large table/view within manageable time?

PS: I also tried `pyodbc`, it's same issue. Changing query to `select top 100 * from view_name` is fast, as expected.

Comment: Why are you trying to return 500 million rows to your application anyway? That isn't usable. And if this is a job then I would expect it to take a long time with 500 million rows. But the execute method does what it states, it executes the query you pass it.

Comment: Yes, returning 100 rows will take less time than 500,000,000... `execute` means execute, just as you would think it means. You seem to be "wanting" to change the definitions of words a bit here...

Comment: Check out [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) for some ideas on pagination.

Comment: Why not use Pandas with sql server?...

Comment: This a batch process, not an app. I need to process this data a bit and move to different place. I assumed execute was lazy as there are fetchall and fetchmeny methods available. If full result is already available, I don't see any point in calling fetchall. It just seems to convert result to list.

Comment: Why can't you process data on server? SQL Server supports querying across schemas/databases on server or [linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) if migrating to other RDBMS' (Oracle, Postgres, DB2, MySQL, etc.).

Comment: I can't speak for pymssql, but pyodbc definitely does not fetch all rows on `.execute`. A quick Wireshark test with default transaction isolation (READ_COMMITTED) shows -- Connect to SQL Server: 8_960 bytes; Execute "SELECT * FROM MillionRows": 82_310 bytes; fetchmany(5_000): 314_810 bytes; fetchmany(995_000): 62_564_304 bytes

Comment: Does that mean @GordThompson that pyodbc makes use of server side cursors to avoid loading the entire result set into memory on the client side?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, after quite some debugging session, I have a solution.

Part of the issue turned out to be underlying view which is very slow. I misjudged this because database client like DBeaver returns result pretty fast (likely because it applies pagination to query behind the scene?). Anyway, what I was trying to do with `cursor.fetchmany`, I did it with Database feature.

SQL Server 12 and later has very nice pagination feature using `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT`. So my solution looks something like this:

```
offset = 0
offset_increment = 200000

def get_chunk(cursor, offset):
    query = f"""
            SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY some_col 
            OFFSET {offset} ROWS FETCH NEXT {offset_incriment} ROWS ONLY;
            """
    return cursor.execute(query).fetchall()

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(6) as executor:
    chunk = get_chunk(query, offset)

    while chunk:
        executor.submit(process_chunk, chunk)
        offset += offset_increment
        chunk = get_chunk(query, offset)
```

So the implementation here is to:

- Use SQL Server pagination feature with `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` to get only limited number of rows.
- Process chunks in parallel using multiple threads. You could also parallelize SQL query execution part to make it faster. That needs bit more work as you need to know when to stop.

This is basic idea behind my solution. Above code is just an example, in reality I had to do many more tuning in my project based on resource usage (mainly memory). You can also you `ProcessPoolExecutor` to do multiprocessing instead of threading. Idea is same, code needs bit of changes as multiprocessing needs only pickalable objects.

So using pagination and processing results concurrently in chunks, you can work with large tables/views pretty easily :)

Comment: Does this omit the first 200000 records? Should offset initially be set to zero?